# TextView incorrect link parsing

Tags: android, text, textview

I would like to have alert message in my textView. This message should contain some clickable link, application package and version.

I use:

```
messageView.setText(message);
Linkify.addLinks(messageView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

My problem is I have complete mess with result text.

Example:

*application com.example.sampleapp.appname version: 2.0.0.0 failed to login. Please contact www.google.com for details.*

In the message above com.example.sampleapp and 2.0.0.0 are also defined as links. How can I prevent this. Maybe some cool regex may help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to use HTML in your text to have complete control of what is clickable:

```
messageView.setText(Html.fromHtml("application com.example.sampleapp.appname version: 2.0.0.0 failed to login. Please contact <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> for details."));
```